# I instantiate an extra duplicate and I cant find it

Tags: java, swing, duplicates

So here is my class Game and I need it to be the one running and dealing with new games. As soon as I press the Jbutton newGame a new game Jpanel should start existing and a new cycle should run apart from one little detail. Every single time I run the game, finish it, and put new game a second time it runs the methods KoniecHry 2, once with the correct panel and one time with a panel holding value NULL and throws a nullpointer exception, also the JOptionPane dialogue is thrown twice with the first one being thrown with the previous sessions names and once with a null
Any ideas where am I duplicating these instances?

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    public static final int SIRKA_OKNA = 1000;
    public static final int VYSKA_OKNA = 600;
    public static final int SIRKA_KARTY = SIRKA_OKNA/15;
    public static final int VYSKA_KARTY = VYSKA_OKNA/10;
    public static final int MEDZERA_OBJEKTOV = SIRKA_KARTY/20;
    public static final int SIRKA_POSUVACA = SIRKA_KARTY/3;
    private final ArrayList <JButton> mainMenu;
    private final Font typPisma;
    private static Game game;
    private Table table;
    private String nameOfTheWinner;
    private Panel panel;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Game.game=new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Game.SIRKA_OKNA,Game.VYSKA_OKNA));
        game.setUndecorated(true);
        game.setResizable(false);
        game.pack();
        game.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Game(){
        typPisma              = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        mainMenu              = new ArrayList<>(); 
        GridLayout rozlozenie = new GridLayout(6,2,50,50);
        JButton newGame       = new JButton("New Game");
        JButton exitGame      = new JButton("Exit Game");

        this.setLayout(rozlozenie);
        this.hlavneMenu.add(newGame);
        this.add(newGame);
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){           
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                game.newGame();
                game.zmenStavMenu(false);
            }
        });

        hlavneMenu.add(exitGame);
        this.add(exitGame);
        exitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }); 
    }   

    class Panel extends JPanel {
        private Table table;
        private Game game;
        Panel(Table table,Game game) {           
            this.table= table;
            this.game = game;
            String menoPrvehoHraca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Ako sa volá hráč č.1?");
            String menoDruhehoHraca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Ako sa volá hráč č.2?");
            this.table= new table(this.game,this,10,menoPrvehoHraca,menoDruhehoHraca);
            game.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            game.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            System.out.println("Vytvoril sa panel");
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            if (this.table!=  null) {
                g.setFont(typPisma);
                this.table.paint(g);
            }
            if(game.nameOfTheWinner!= null) {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.SIRKA_OKNA, Game.VYSKA_OKNA);
            } 
        }
    }

    public void endOfTheGame(String nameOfTheWinner) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nameOfTheWinner+ " vyhral hru");
        this.nameOfTheWinner= nameOfTheWinner;
        this.panel.repaint();
        this.table= null;
        this.panel = null;
        this.zmenStavMenu(true);
    }

    private void newGame(){
        this.panel = new Panel(this.table,this);
        this.nameOfTheWinner= null;
    }

    private void changeState(boolean state) {
        for(JButton currentButton: this.mainMenu){
            currentButton.setVisible(state);
            currentButton.setEnabled(state);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You appear to be creating a new Panel object, but you're not placing it into any GUI that I can see. It's just hanging there.

Comment: I add it into the frame withtin the panel constructor am I wrong?  with this command  game.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: Ah, I see, it's going into code not shown to us, some class called Stol.

Comment: true, and when the class stol is finished ( the game sesion has ended) I call the method KoniecHry from game to anull the reference to it

Comment: For better help, post a [mcve], a small program that we can compile and run and test and modify that is small enough to post here as code-formatted text, and that only has code that is relevant to your problem adn that allows your program to compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the error. I kept on having an instance of mouseListener which kept alive another button which never cease to exist so when I closed the game second time both buttons from the game before and the next one started so and problem was that the certain objects werent there anymore so I was getting a null point